# Store a formula in a table and use the formula in a javascript/PHP function

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have a MySql database where part of it handles instrument's depth of water. Each instrument has its own formula of calculation how depth the water when the operator collect the reading I stored the formula for each instrument in database/MySql.

**Example formula**: `[55-57]`

this is the simple minus operation, where the number is actually represent the id of a row. How do I represent those number with id of a row and later convert it to javascript readable code. I simply want to do keyup event where everytime user key in something into text field then the other part of HTML would reflect changes based on formula that I fetched from database

FYI, I'm using BackboneJS together with RequireJS

Comment: This apears to be one of the few occasions where you might want to read up  on `eval()`. Use with care ;)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **programming** which is off-topic at Pro Webmasters. Programming questions may be asked at [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) but be sure to read their [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting to ensure your question meets their guidelines.